# Error while using Ckeditor - CKEditorError: plugincollection-required

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I'm using ckeditor in one of my project but edit is not displayed on the webpage due to following issue.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): CKEditorError:
> plugincollection-required
> {"plugin":"ImageUpload","requiredBy":"EasyImage"}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the installation guide for angular?https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular

npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

In your `appModule.ts` you need to import it

```
import { CKEditorModule } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular';
```

@NgModule( {
imports: [
CKEditorModule,
// ...
],
// ...
} )

Comment: yes, this is exactly same. But still the editor is not displayed on UI and browser console has the following error: core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): CKEditorError: plugincollection-required {"plugin":"ImageUpload","requiredBy":"EasyImage"}
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-plugincollection-required

Answer (score 0):

as CKEditor5 office documents said: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-plugincollection-required

Did you have moved 'ImageUpload' by config `removePlugins: ['ImageUpload']`

I have reappear your issue by upper case.

Comment: Yes, I did it in following method:
setEditorConfig() {
    this.ckeConfig = {
      removePlugins: ['ImageUpload', 'MediaEmbed'],
      heading: {
        options: [

Answer (score 0):

just write this it will resolve the issue

```
removePlugins: ['imageUpload', 'mediaEmbed'],
```